# Is it OK to extract datasets from somebody's paper and work with it in your own papers?

Tags: publications, data

Let's say David Smith has published a paper a while ago. In this paper there are some results plotted in a graph. I want to use this dataset in my own research and extend it with my own results. Unfortunately, it is not possible to contact David Smith. So I use some of tools [mentioned for example in this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/software-for-extracting-data-from-a-graph-without-having-to-click-on-every-singl/19639#19639) to extract the dataset from the plot (which, of course, might introduce some kind of small errors).

Do you consider it as OK if I now publish a paper which includes the old dataset from David Smith + my new data in a new plot? I would, of course, cite the old paper by David Smith. (I might deduce some results from the old+new data that a somewhat different that the original conclusion by David Smith.)

Comment: Can you elaborate why you have doubts regarding if it is OK?

Comment: @Roland my doubts are about extracting the data with software-tools from their plots and do further research with it - instead of having the proper (real/raw) dataset and allowance from the original author.

Comment: I'd understood what your doubts are about. What I'm interested in is *why* you have doubts. Such information could help writing more specific answers. Extracting data from graphs has a long tradition. I can't see how anybody would suspect ethical problems if proper citation rules are observed. That's why I'm asking you for your reasoning.

Comment: @Roland I see, let my try to explain: I think my *personal feeling* is that using these tools to extract data feels a bit like just copying somebody's data + I might introduce errors by extracting the data which could lead to wrong conclusions about the original dataset (only on a first check, though, a through check would/should reveal that *I* made an error). But that issue is tackled by JayFromA's answer.

Comment: Extracting data shouldn't introduce errors if done right. It usually introduces additional uncertainty which can be taken into account for subsequent analyses. A graph is just a different way of presenting information than a table. Would you have the same doubts with extracting data from a table?

Comment: @Roland I see what you mean and I guess I was just a bit too, hmm, maybe *cautious* or *shy* but it principle everything published is something I can further use or work with I guess (with proper acknowledgement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you cite the original authors in your plots and when comparing results/conclusions (or simply everywhere you use their data/work) you should be fine.
Also make it clear that the data is "reverse engineered" from their graphs/plots and not the "original" data.

Comment: clearly stating that it is "reversed engineered" instead of saying "old data from Ref. [xx]", I like that idea, thanks!

Comment: Good answer. I would also like to mention that meta-analyses are doing exactly that, with lots of articles!